# How do I read values from config.php file to another file

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to coding with php and I need help with this.

I have a config.php file with these values

```
<?php
 define('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost');
 define('DATABASE_NAME', 'voltrun');
 define('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'joy');
 define('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'salty');
 ?>
```

I have also a db.php file with these values

```
<?php require_once"../config.php";
 echo 'DATABASE_HOST';
 echo 'DATABASE_NAME';
 echo 'DATABASE_USERNAME';
 echo 'DATABASE_PASSWORD'

  $db_host = 'DATABASE_HOST';
  $db_user = 'DATABASE_USERNAME';
  $db_password =  'DATABASE_PASSWORD';
  $db_database = 'DATABASE_NAME';

   $connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password,    $db_database);

      if (!$connection) {
die('QUERY FAILED' . mysqli_error($connection));
   } 


   ?>
```

Any help on how to get the parameters from the config.php file into the db.php variables? As I still get Query Failed error.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `echo 'DATABASE_HOST';` (etc.) that's a constant; you're treating it as a string literal. You don't need the quotes, same for the others. Plus missing semi-colon in `echo 'DATABASE_PASSWORD'`

Comment: `DATABASE_HOST` defined as `constant` and you are doing `echo 'DATABASE_HOST'`..

Comment: @Fred thanks for the pointer, Issue now resolved, b0s3 thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code:

```
 echo 'DATABASE_HOST';
 echo 'DATABASE_NAME';
 echo 'DATABASE_USERNAME';
 echo 'DATABASE_PASSWORD'
                         ^ missing ; if that's your actual code.

  $db_host = 'DATABASE_HOST';
  $db_user = 'DATABASE_USERNAME';
  $db_password =  'DATABASE_PASSWORD';
  $db_database = 'DATABASE_NAME';
```

You've wrapped all your [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) in quotes, treating them as [string literals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php); **remove them**.

Plus, you've a missing semi-colon:

```
 echo DATABASE_HOST;
 echo DATABASE_NAME;
 echo DATABASE_USERNAME;
 echo DATABASE_PASSWORD; // < Added the missing semi-colon
```

that error reporting would have thrown a parse error

```
  $db_host = DATABASE_HOST;
  $db_user = DATABASE_USERNAME;
  $db_password =  DATABASE_PASSWORD;
  $db_database = DATABASE_NAME;
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Also make sure that this is correct:

```
require_once"../config.php";
```

Error reporting will tell you that also.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was almost loosing my mind over this, and to think it was because I wrapped constants in quotes?

Comment: @user3650900 You're most welcome. Indeed, the quotes for the constants; there should not be any.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include/require the config file - then it gots executed and you could use the constants, you define in the conf file as any other constant.

```
include "config.php";
$db_host = DATABASE_HOST;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'DATABASE_HOST';
```

This is `echo`ing "DATABASE_HOST". You want to use the **value**, so you do this:

```
echo DATABASE_HOST;
```

Notice the quotation marks are gone.

You'd remove them when assigning to another variable too

```
$db_host = DATABASE_HOST;
```